# SVN client for Ubuntu with Context menu

Tags: ubuntu, svn, gui

I've been wondering if there's an SVN client for Ubuntu (10.04 lucid lynx) in Gnome (not kdesvn since it's for kde) with context menu, so if you right-click on an SVN repository you have the options to branch and what-not (just like tortoise SVN on windows)..

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend [RabbitVCS](http://www.rabbitvcs.org/) - it works pretty much the same way as Tortoise SVN by adding status icons to files/folders as well as SVN actions to the right-click context menu in Nautilus.

To install RabbitSVN on Ubuntu, you will need to launch the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus
```

You may need to log out/in so that nautilus is restarted and RabbitVCS shows.

Comment: You can restart nautilus in terminal by typing sudo killall nautilus. Gnome restarts nautilus afterwards. Thanks for the heads up on the client!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [kdesvn](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de/)...It is pretty and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [SVN workbench](http://pysvn.tigris.org/).. It's not exactly like Tortoisesvn, but it's quite nice IMHO.